# Help with integrating latest Delphi Web Script (DWS) with SynEdit

Tags: delphi, ide, synedit, dwscript

I decided to have a concerted effort to get the excellent [DWScript (Delph Web Script DWS)](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/) integrated into a simple IDE using [SynEdit](http://synedit.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/synedit/). DWScript is currently being [agressively developed](http://delphitools.info/) and has a number of advantages over other Pascal Script libraries, however it does not contain an editor or any IDE example beyond a simple memo control to prove execution capability. It does contain a number of hooks for editor / debugger integration and in fact when DWS was reawakened a while ago, releases did contain an example of a SynEdit / DWS2 (as it was then) integration. An example can be found in the file [dws2src20-20030907.zip](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_dws/releases/) in the \dws2rel\dwstools\idedialog\source where there is a 'mini-IDE' with editor window, call stack, breakpoint window etc. Really nice. I did get this working some months ago using an old SynEdit and the DWS2 that was included in this file.

So, I have now tried achieve this (or a similar) ide using the latest SynEdit (downloaded from SVN) and the latest DWScript (also from the SVN). Both libraries are installed fine into XE and their demos run fine. I then tried taking the ide example from the old "\dws2rel\dwstools\idedialog\source" and updating the code but much has changed. Frustratingly, not so much has changed that I gave up quickly - I tried searching for the various 'old' type definitions in old source and matching them up with 'new' definitions. Finally though, after several hours mired in code I decided that someone, somewhere must surely have been down this route?

Has anyone got an example of a DWScript - SynEdit integration using recent DWScript code please? I'm very happy with something simple that I can learn / build upon.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SynEdit component has received little maintenance, and even some projects as [Inno Setup](http://%20Http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) have changed to [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/), [Inno Setup](http://%20Http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is not using DWS but the code can serve you as a basis for new IDE

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will take a look at the latest Innosetup source.

Comment: Yes, I also use Scintilla too for my live html5/css real-time editor: [LIVEditor](http://liveditor.com)

Answer (score 0):

Dws have a editor on the demos with debuger and remote debuger just download all versions of dws one

Comment: I should probably update this question. I have now created an IDE which you can find in the Trunk/Tools section of the DWS googlescript code http://dwscript.googlecode.com/svn. It is still very much beta but is designed to look 'Delphi-like'. There is  documentation with it.